# In Ruby- Parsing Directory and reading first row of the file

Tags: ruby, fileparsing

Below is the piece of code that is supposed read the directory and for each file entry prints the first row of the file. The issue is x is not visible so file is not being parsed.

```
Dir.foreach("C:/fileload/src") do |file_name|
  x = file_name
  puts x
  f = File.open("C:/fileload/src/" +x)
  f.readlines[1..1].each do |line| 
    puts line 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you assigning `x` to `file_name`?  You can use `file_name` directly.  And if you are only reading the first line of the file, why not try this?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

dir = "C:/fileload/src"
Dir.foreach(dir) do |file_name|
    full = File.join(dir, file_name)
    if File.file?(full)
        f = File.open(full)
        puts f.first
        f.close
    end
end
```

You should use [File.join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join) to safely combine paths in Ruby.  I also checked that you are opening a file using the [File.file?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-file-3F) method.

Comment: Thank you . Appreciate your answer . This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish . Thanks for the insight into f.first and File.join

Answer (score 2):

You have no visibility issue with `x`.  You should be using [`File::join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join) or [`Pathname#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-2B) to build your file paths. You should exclude non-files from consideration. You're selecting the second line, not the first with `[1..1]`.  Here's a cleaner correct replacement for your sample code.

```
dir = "C:/fileload/src"
Dir.foreach(dir).
map    { |fn| File.join(dir,fn) }.
select { |fn| File.file?(fn) }.
each   { |fn| puts File.readlines(fn).first }
```

Comment: This is quite an interesting approach, it made me think for a while.

Comment: @squiguy The idea is not to make you think, but to say what you want plainly.  Once you're used to thinking/reading in the more functional style, this just reads like a recipe: 1) produce directory list, 2) map names to paths, 3) select those that are files, 4) print the first line of each file.

Comment: I'm not against functional styles, I just appreciate it :).

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaining the code. As you can seeI'm newbie to ruby . Thanks again!